# Trouble evaluating the complex integral $\int_{\Gamma} e^z dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate $\int_{\Gamma} e^z dz$, where $\Gamma$ is the graph of $y= \sin x$ parametrized by $x=0$ to $x= \pi$.

I tried applying the following theorem to solve the integral:

> Let $f(z)$ be continuous in a domain $\Omega$ and suppose $F(z)$ is a function defined, analytic, and satisfying $F^{\prime}(z)=f(z)$ at all points $z \in \Omega$. If $\Gamma$ is a curve in $\Omega$ from $z_0$ to $z_1$, then $$\int_{\Gamma} f(z) dz = \int_{\Gamma} F^{\prime}(z) dz = F(z_1)-F(z_0).$$

In this case, $f(z)=e^z$ is continuous in $\Omega= \mathbb{C}$ and $F(z)=e^z$ is defined and analytic. But I am having trouble convincing myself that $\Gamma=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:y= \sin x,\, 0 \leqslant x \leqslant \pi\}$ is contained in $\Omega= \mathbb{C}$. I thought $\mathbb{R}^2$ and subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ were not contained in $\mathbb{C}$? Applying the theorem yields the right answer but I am not sure if I can actually use it...

Comment: I would think that what they mean by $\Gamma$ is $\Gamma = \{x+iy~:~ y=\sin(x),~~x\in[0,\pi]\}$.

Comment: @Winther thanks, that makes more sense.